# Breaking a large table into smaller ones for export

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a very large table in MS Access which exceeds the amount of lines Excel can hold.  Due to licensing issues, we cannot use access as an external data source, we can, however use Excel to store the tables until we can use SQL Server which is coming in several months.

I have been tasked with breaking up the table into countries.

Getting a query for getting all the distinct countries is no problem.

```
Select distinct Country_Code
from AllCountries
```

But then I need to get a result set for each country.

I've been to several sites trying to figure this out before coming here.
I know it's a basic question, unfortunately, a stroke and 10 years away from the field has left me rusty.

I need to create these smaller tables 0r result sets and export them.  I'm lost on this one.

Comment: what kind of access (no pun intended lol) will users need to the tables during the next few months?  can't you use the Access Database Engine now called Access 2016 Run time (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040) that is freely redistributed and then query from within Excel as needed?  I definitely do NOT want to recommend splitting this up and putting it in a format so easily manipulated by users.  What is the real goal, what level of use, etc.? Would MySQL or PostgresSQL be an option for a temporary amount of time they are freely licensed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```vb
PUBLIC FUNCTION exportFiles() AS Boolean
    Dim db AS DAO.DATABASE
    Dim qdf AS DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rsRptGroup AS DAO.Recordset
    Dim sSQL AS String
    Dim sRptGroup AS String
    Dim sPath AS String

    Const sQryExport AS String = "qryExport"

    sPath = Application.CurrentProject.PATH

    SET db = CurrentDb
    SET qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(sQryExport, sSQL)
    qdf.NAME = sQryExport

    ' Get list of labeler values
    sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT labeler FROM qry_export"
    Set rsRptGroup = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)

    ' Now LOOP THROUGH list OF labeler VALUES AND CREATE a QUERY FOR EACH labeler
    ' so that the data can be exported
    Do While Not rsRptGroup.EOF
        sRptGroup = rsRptGroup("labeler")
        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM qry_export WHERE labeler = '" & sRptGroup & "'"
        qdf.sql = sSQL

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, sQryExport, sPath & "\xls\" & sRptGroup & ".xls"

        rsRptGroup.MoveNext
    Loop

    rsRptGroup.Close
    Set rsRptGroup = Nothing    
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing    
    exportFiles = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Reconsider your setup as your claim is not entirely correct:

> Due to licensing issues, we cannot use access as an external data
>   source

MS Access .mdb/.accdb files can be used by any PC machine regardless of the MSAccess.exe program which does require licensing. The underlying technology of MS Access is the JET/ACE SQL Engine which is a set of Windows .dll files, usually pre-installed on PC machines. Access is just a GUI that uses this engine by default.

So continue to use an actual relational database (.mdb/.accdb) files and not flatfile Excel worksheets for data storage and integrity. On machines without Access, files will show up with blank icons unable to be opened directly with any one program but can be connected with Excel or other langauges (PHP, R, Python, Java) via ODBC/OLEDB connections or COM objects --ADO or DAO. In fact, Windows computers can create .mdb/.accdb files without the full fledged Access program. Below are Excel macros for illustration:

**CREATE DATABASE**  *(with DAO)*

```vb
Sub CreateDatabase()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim olDb As Object, db As Object
    Dim strpath As String
    Const dbLangGeneral = ";LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0"

    strpath = "C:\Path\To\Access\Database.accdb"

    ' CREATE DATABASE
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set olDb = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")

    If Not fso.FileExists(strpath) Then
        Set db = olDb.CreateDatabase(strpath, dbLangGeneral)
    End If

    Set db = Nothing
    Set olDb = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

    MsgBox "Successfully created database!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**CREATE TABLES**  *(with ADO)*

```vb
Sub CreateTables()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim strpath As String, constr As String
    Dim objAccess As Object
    Dim conn As Object

    strpath = "C:\Path\To\Access\Database.accdb"

    ' CONNECT TO DATABASE
    constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strpath & ";"
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open constr

    ' CREATE TABLES
    conn.Execute "CREATE TABLE Clients (" _
                    & " ClientID AUTOINCREMENT," _
                    & " ClientName TEXT(255)," _
                    & " Address TEXT(255)," _
                    & " Notes TEXT(255)," _
                    & " DateCreated DATETIME" _
                    & ");"

    conn.Execute "CREATE TABLE Orders (" _
                    & " OrderID AUTOINCREMENT," _
                    & " ClientID INTEGER," _
                    & " Item TEXT(255)," _
                    & " Price DOUBLE," _
                    & " OrderDate DATETIME," _
                    & " Notes TEXT(255)" _
                    & ");"

    ' CLOSE CONNECTION
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

    MsgBox "Successfully created Clients and Orders tables!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Additionally, if you require a GUI application of MS Access with forms, reports, macros, and modules, only one person (developer) needs to have the full fledged MS Access to make design changes to database. Meanwhile, all others (users) can use free Runtime versions available for download via Microsoft.com: [2007](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4438) / [2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910) / [2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358) / [2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040). Just be sure to have database run without need of a Navigation Pane (i.e., Main Menu navigation).