# In Microsoft Access 2007, how can I print a grouped report so each grouping is sent as a separate print job..?

Tags: ms-access

I have a report in Microsoft 2007 which has one level of grouping on the first column by customer. The report can be 50-200+ pages long, but each grouped section can be about 1-5 pages. If when printing the report, is there any simple method of sending each group to the printer as a separate print job..??

The reason for this is our printer has a stapler, and if the report could be automatically stapled by group, it would be quite a boon to our dispatcher during our busy seasons.

If there is no easy way of doing this, I would assume that means a macro or VBA. If that's the case, what would be the best approach..?? I'm vaguely thinking of a parameter query that's called/nested from a parent query that finds all the customer numbers in the daily data, but someone with more experience might offer a better suggestion.

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712408/breaking-a-large-table-into-smaller-ones-for-export/39712585#39712585)?

Comment: Staring at the code for a bit, it does seem like it will get me pretty close. I'll have to modify it to print instead of export as XLS. I won't have time to test this before xmas rolls over. I'll work on it next week and let you know what happens.

Comment: yes, try openReport() instead of exporting to Excel, the idea of grouping by a field value is the same